# What is securityfs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, security, sysfs, procfs

While I am studying, I saw security file system which is mounted on /sys/kernel/security . It seems like to operate similar to sysfs or proc file system. Security file system keeps data on memory not in disk, so when write something into the file in securityfs it does not actually write to disk just update data in memory.

What I am wondering is why the name of this file system is securityfs?
Is there any security enhance ability in this file system?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/153366/ might be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links regarding securityfs:

- [A post from the author of securityfs](https://lwn.net/Articles/153366)
- [Article about PipeFS, SockFS, DebugFS, and SecurityFS](https://www.linux.org/threads/pipefs-sockfs-debugfs-and-securityfs.9638/).

The author stats:

> This filesystem is meant to be used by security modules, some of which
>   were otherwise creating their own filesystems.

So I guess the name comes from the [Linux Security Modules (LSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules).